# Add tag around matches in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am currently trying to write a piece of code that adds html bold tags around figures found in a text.

**Here's my input text :**

*I think he was a 100 percent guy. I think he was a 100 % guy. I think he was a 100 per cent guy*

**Here's what I want :**

*I think he was a **100 percent** guy. I think he was a **100 %** guy. I think he was a **100 per cent** guy*.

**But that's what I get :**

*I think he was a **100 percent** 100 percent guy. I think he was a **100 %** 100 % guy. I think he was a **100 per cent** 100 per cent guy.*

```
import re

taggedOutput=""
myInput = "I think he was a 100 percent guy \n I think he was a 100 % \guy \n I think he was a 100 per cent guy"
pattern ="(([0-9]+ ?)(%|percent|per cent))"
regex = re.compile(pattern)

# I use re.split to isolate the content I want to tag... I guess the problem is there...
chunks = re.split(regex,myInput)
#For every chunk
for chunk in chunks:
    if chunk != None:
        matchStat = re.match(regex,chunk)
        if matchStat:
            taggedOutput += '<B>'+chunk+'</B>'
        else :
            taggedOutput += chunk
#print
print('<P>'+taggedOutput+'</P>')
```

Thanks you in advance ;)

Comment: ...what's your question?

Comment: It's more easy with a string replacement, but if you want to do it with a split, change the two innermost capture groups to non-capturing groups.

Comment: I'd like to have the output I'm looking for. I don't understand why re.split behave like this,  and what can I use to get the right result =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) instead referencing the captured group via `\1`:

```
pattern = r"(([0-9]+ ?)(%|percent|per cent))"
print(re.sub(pattern, r"<b>\1</b>", myInput))
```